# Javascript get value of current number input field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a shopping cart. Now i want to update the price of the item when the amount is changed, but when there are more than one items the onchange method only reacts on the first one. They have the same name. I can give them an other name but how will i then get the name of that input field.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

```
function updatePrice() {
    var element = this;

    console.log(element.value);
}
```

Comment: We need more code than that to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onchange event should iterate over all input fields.
If you give your fields a common identifier (a data-id attribute or a class name), then the process is quite trivial:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("change", ()=> calc());

function calc(){

  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".inp");
  let total = 0.0;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    total += parseFloat(items[i].value);
  }
  document.querySelector(".result").value = total.toFixed(2);
}

calc();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inp" value="10.00">
<input type="text" class="inp" value="15.00">
<input type="text" class="inp" value="50.99">
<p>Result: <input type="text" class="result" value="00.00"></p>
```